# Django modelformset order_by not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to use a Django (1.4) modelformset in which, when the formset is loaded the forms will be arranged by a exam_date field I have in my model. To do this I've created the following simple BaseModelFormSet

```
class BaseExamDateFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseExamDateFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = models.ExamDate.objects.all().order_by('exam_date')
```

As you can see I've changed the queryset as proposed in the 
[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) (later I'll also change its clean method but it doesn't matter right now). After that I am using it in my view to create the formset:

```
ExamDateFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    models.ExamDate, 
    exclude =('authority', ), 
    can_delete=True, 
    extra=1,
    formset = forms.BaseExamDateFormSet
)
...
formset = ExamDateFormSet()
```

My problem is that when the formset is rendered the data in the forms is always in the same ordering (probaby by id) regardless of the value of the order_by attribute :(

Should I try setting a default order by in my ExamDate model ? I really don't like that solution though :(

TIA !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more searching I found a solution !

I ignored the queryset attribute and added the following method to the BaseExamDateFormSet:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return models.ExamDate.objects.all().order_by('exam_date')
```

However I don't know yet why the queryset attribute isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Easier still, in your above code you could erase your formset= argument in modelformset_factory call and instantiate your formset as:

```
formset = ExamDateFormSet(queryset=models.ExamDate.objects.order_by('exam_date'))
```

Comment: Passing queryset as a kwarg actually works ? I'm not able to test it right now because it's an old project :(

Comment: It does work, for the record i'm using rather old django v1.4.9. Probably still supported.